# How do I get code coverage of AWS Device Farm tests with Android?

Tags: android, android-instrumentation, aws-device-farm

I am running instrumentation tests on AWS Device Farm and can download the results of the tests but do not see any *.exec or *.ec files in the results.  This is what I typically see when running tests locally with an attached device/emulator using Gradle.

Does AWS Device Farm support code coverage?

Comment: If you found it helpful please accept the answer so that others can benefit too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work for the AWS Device Farm team.
Unfortunately, that artifact isn't exposed yet on device farm.

I have made a note of it in our product backlog.
I am curious if you can obtain the same thing if you were not running from Android studio at all.

Comment: Hi , I wonder if I can get code coverage from Device Farm with iOS XCTest?

Comment: @NikofTime Any advancements here? I would love to be able to gather the .ec output of at least one of the run devices for reporting with jacoco.

Comment: And is this still in the product backlog?